# Python error: execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

Tags: python, psycopg2, gevent

How do I prevent the error “`ProgrammingError: execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway`”? From the docs it says that I should use psycopg2.extras.wait_select if I’m using a coroutine support like gevent., but I’m still get that error when I’m using it. I’ve isolated the error I’m getting in the snippet below.

```
con = psycopg2.connect(database=DATABASE_NAME, user=DATABASE_USERNAME)

def execute_query(cur, query, params):
    psycopg2.extras.wait_select(con)
    cur.execute(query, params)
    psycopg2.extras.wait_select(con)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print rows[0]

cur = con.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
gevent.joinall([
     gevent.spawn(execute_query, cur, query, None),
     gevent.spawn(execute_query, cur, query, None),
     gevent.spawn(execute_query, cur, query, None),
     gevent.spawn(execute_query, cur, query, None)
])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to do more than one transaction simultaneously on a single connection. The psycopg documentation says that this is not thread safe and will lead to an error. See under [Asynchronous support and Support for coroutine libraries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html)

One possible solution is to use one database connection, each with one cursor, per coroutine (4 distinct connections and cursors in this case).

Comment: So I tried your suggestion, and created the cursor in the 'execute_query' method and I still get the same error.

Comment: did you try one connection as in code sample, or four connections/cursors (one each per coroutine)?

Comment: Oh. My mistake. With four connections, the error goes away. But I wonder about the efficiency of using a new connection every time I want to do a single query.

Comment: You could reuse the connections after your four transactions complete on other transactions, you just need to have a distinct connection/cursor assigned to each coroutine if you are going to do queries concurrently.