# execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, psycopg2

I constantly get an error

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway`

As I understand it, because of that I am trying to use the data while the request has not yet been completed. How can I fix it? I use something like this(flask+socket.io+psycopg2) if I shorten the code to just a good example:

```
def wait(conn):
    while True:
        state = conn.poll()
        if state == psycopg2.extensions.POLL_OK:
            break
        elif state == psycopg2.extensions.POLL_WRITE:
            select.select([], [conn.fileno()], [])
        elif state == psycopg2.extensions.POLL_READ:
            select.select([conn.fileno()], [], [])
        else:
            raise psycopg2.OperationalError("poll() returned %s" % state)

try:
    aconn = psycopg2.connect(f"dbname='{db_name}' user='{db_user}' host='{db_host}' password='{db_pass}'", async_=1)
    wait(aconn)
    c = aconn.cursor()
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception:', str(e))

@socketio.on('uploaddata')
def on_send(data):
    id = data['id']
    lablvlid = data['lablvlID']
    player = data['player']
    s = f"select * from cart_plcl where id='{id}' and lablvlid ='{lablvlid}' and player='{player}'"
    c.execute(s)
    wait(c.connection)
    result = c.fetchall()
    for r in result:
        #do something
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error: execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869118/python-error-execute-cannot-be-used-while-an-asynchronous-query-is-underway)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I made a new connection to the database and it helped, but I think it’s not good to open the connection every time.